# Why are recent entries in Windows Start Bar never up-to-date

Tags: windows

Running Windows (5,6,7), I have always pinned *Mathematica* to the **Start Bar**.  This feature offers the **Recent files** for a quick load.  However, the list of files has never been up-to-date, i.e., I can never access my most recently opened *Mathematica* files.

I would agree that it is not very important, but then again it is a quite helpful feature. How do I get the entries to be up-to-date?

Comment: I believe the Recent Files function works as intended.  Perhaps you are expecting it to include files opened from inside *Mathematica* when in fact it shows files opened from within Explorer?

Comment: The answer would be that the entires in the Start Menu reflect the files I opened using the Explorer and is no entry, which is influenced by Mathematica?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I guess your comment contains the answer (i.e. the difference between Windows´ and Mathematica´s recent files).

Answer (score 3):

The answer seems to be that the entires in the Start Menu reflect the files one has opened using the Explorer, while filenames visible in the *Mathematica* File Menu stem from opening a file from within *Mathematica*.   The entires in the Start Menu are not influenced by *Mathematica* or any other application.  Therefore, the two lists usually show different file names.

For completeness, this is also the behavior in the `Apple > Recent Items > Documents` menu on OS X.

Comment: it's perhaps useful to point out that other applications on OS X display all recently opened files in this menu (and also on the Dock menu); that is, also files opened by eg File->Open